# Get records using multiple conditions in DynamoDB in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a new user in dynamodb but before that I want to check that user is present in db or not. Here Primary partition key   is username. I Want to check both emailId and username in the condition. Both should be unique. For example

```
user1 user1@gmail.com
user2 user2@gmail.com
user3 user3@gmail.com
```

**Example1** When I create a new user **username= user4** and **emailId=user1@gmail.com** It should not create a new user because emailId is already present.

**Example2** When I create a new user **username= user1** and **emailId=user4@gmail.com** It should not create a new user because  username is already present.

So these are the scenarios. Can anybody tell what is the best  solution for this?

I found the solution using **scan** method

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb_DocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    let params = {
        TableName: "OP-User",
        ProjectionExpression: 'userName, emailAddress',
        FilterExpression: "userName = :userName OR emailAddress = :emailAddress",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":userName": "user1",
          ":emailAddress": "user111@asurion.com"
        }
      };

      dynamoDb_DocumentClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("err:  " + err);
        }
        console.log("data:  " + data);
      });
```

Can we have another solution for this ? using **Query, Indexname**? like this.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS DynamoDB [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to compare Username and ID attributes, before creating and item.